# How to fire/move to OriginalSource EventHandler?

Tags: wpf, events

I have a usercontrol ROOT_CONTROL that contains another user control SUB_CONTROL , which contains button BUTTON.

ROOT_CONTROL- > SUB -> BUTTON

```
<UserControl x:Name="ROOT_CONTROL"
GotKeyboardFocus="UserControl_GotKeyboardFocus">
<StackPanel>
<UserControl x:Name="SUB_CONTROL">
<Button x:Name="BUTTON" Click="BUTTON_Click">
</UserControl>
</StackPanel>
<SUB_Control>
</UserControl>
```

I have a UserControl_GotKeyboardFocus eventhandler connected with ROOT_CONTROL, I have an Button_Click eventhandler connected with BUTTON. When user clicks on BUTTON and there is a KeyboardFocus on that ROOT_CONTROL - it works ok, but when there is no KeyboardFocus on that control (or any of its children) it fires UserControl_GotKeyboardFocus (and that's ok), but then it does not fire BUTTON click event. 
So when there is no keyboard focus on that control, user needs to click twice to see result (once to give focus, second to fire button event).

I do not change property e.Handled to true inside  UserControl_GotKeyboardFocus  eventhandler.

How to easily (if it is possible) fire BUTTON click eventhandler when there is no keyboardfocus on ROOT_CONTROL?

EDIT:

```
    private void UserControl_GotKeyboardFocus(object sender, KeyboardFocusChangedEventArgs e)
{
    if (Guard)
    {
        Guard = false;
    }
    else
    {
        if (e.OldFocus == null)
        {
            if (SessionData.SelectionWindow != null && !(SessionData.SelectionWindow.Visibility == Visibility.Visible))
            {

                SessionData.SelectionWindow.Ano.UpdateSelection();
                SessionData.SelectionWindow.UpdatePosition();
                SessionData.SelectionWindow.Visibility = Visibility.Visible;
                if (e.OriginalSource is FrameworkElement)
                {
                    (e.OriginalSource as FrameworkElement).Focus();
                }
            }
            else
            {
            }
        }
        else
        {
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: Should work by default. What are you doing in your `GotKeyboardFocus` event handler?

Comment: I have just added content of GotKeyboardFocus event handler.

Comment: Did you try to comment out this code? Does the click event handler get invoked as expected then?

Comment: I've just tried and it works. I will need to investigate what exactly is causing that weird behavior. Thanks!

Comment: That's because of:SessionData.SelectionWindow.Visibility = Visibility.Visible;
SessionData.SelectionWindow is an WPF window and when visibility is changed, keyboardfocus is also moved to that window. And then event is not bubbling up (why? any way to force it?). When I remove that code line, button works like a charm. Unfortunately I still don't know how to resolve the issue, except replacing buttons with some controls that have eventhandler PreviewMouseDown (that is fired before GotKeyboardFocus eventhandler is fired).

Comment: I've just realized that buttons have also PreviewMouseDown and PreviewMouseUp (and that I will use) events...